# Multiple application on single PC

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, server, ip

I have installed **Tomcat server** on my server PC with IP **127.0.0.1**
One application is running on the server. Let address of the application is: *127.0.0.1:8080/first-project* Now if I want to run another application on the same server, address will be: *127.0.0.1:8080/second-project*

I want multiple application with multiple addresses like **127.0.0.1**, **127.0.0.2**

a) Is this possible to have **multiple address on single PC**?

b) What is the best practice for running multiple server on same server and how to do that?

1. With different IP address (127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2)
2. With same IP address but different port (127.0.0.1:8080, 127.0.0.1:8081)
3. With same IP different path (127.0.0.1/first, 127.0.0.1/second)

Any resource link will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of multiple addresses, have multiple ports. For example, 127.0.0.1/8000 for 1st application, 127.0.0.1/8001 for second application and so on. So second option should do.

Comment: All three options are valid. Moreover you can use different host names instead of different IP addresses. Which option you choose is mostly a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert of networking, but what I would suggest to you is the following

1. You can have many application running on the same server, in the same `Tomcat Server` but you have to set differents ports. Example : `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://localhost:8082/` or `http://localhost:8084/`
2. You can run your applications in [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/network/). Then you will be able to run your application in an isolated container with its own `IP address`. With `Docker`, you can use `docker-compose` to run many containers
3. You can run your applications in differents [virtual machines](https://www.oracle.com/virtualization/solutions/try-oracle-vm-virtualbox/?source=:ad:pas:go:dg:a_nas:71700000079711823-58700006707759345-p60691657643:RC_WWMK200609P00103C0001:&SC=:ad:pas:go:dg:a_nas::RC_WWMK200609P00103C0001:&gclsrc=aw.ds&gclid=Cj0KCQjw_fiLBhDOARIsAF4khR0XifxoPL3RGZB_o6v95qPfLmoriQpcr6ONIQKHqgwqV9vyr3Nzyt4aAhk5EALw_wcB). You will be able to configure each virtual machines with their own `IP address` to interact with your `host` or from external location.
4. You can, have multiple `IP address` on a [single](https://serverfault.com/questions/312221/can-a-single-network-card-have-2-ip-addresses) network card

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which one is better? For me 2, 3 looks better.

Comment: I would suggest also the solution `3`. It is a good practice and very popular in the industry, mainly in `microservice` architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Of course every host can have multiple IP addresses. As an example you can refer to the local computer by any address in the range `127.0.0.0-127.255.255.255`.

Also all your configurations are possible and the choice between them in a development environment is a question of taste.

Starting from a minimal Tomcat [Service](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/service.html) configuration:

```xml
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector address="127.0.0.1" port="80"/>
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="dev.localhost">
      <Host name="dev.localhost"  appBase="webapps/dev.localhost"/>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
```

you can:

1. Configure Tomcat to listen on two IP addresses by configuring two services ([IP-based virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#IP-based)):

   ```xml
   <Service name="Catalina-127.0.0.1">
     <Connector address="127.0.0.1" port="80"/>
     <Engine name="Catalina-127.0.0.1" defaultHost="localhost">
       <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps/127.0.0.1"/>
     </Engine>
   </Service>
   <Service name="Catalina-127.0.0.2">
     <Connector address="127.0.0.2" port="80"/>
     <Engine name="Catalina-127.0.0.2" defaultHost="localhost">
       <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps/127.0.0.2"/>
     </Engine>
   </Service>
   ```
2. Configure Tomcat to listen on two different ports by configuring two services ([Port-based virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Port-based)):

   ```xml
   <Service name="Catalina-8080">
     <Connector port="8080"/>
     <Engine name="Catalina-8080" defaultHost="localhost">
       <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps/8080"/>
     </Engine>
   </Service>
   <Service name="Catalina-8081">
     <Connector port="8081"/>
     <Engine name="Catalina-8081" defaultHost="localhost">
       <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps/8081"/>
     </Engine>
   </Service>
   ```
3. Configure Tomcat with two virtual hosts ([Name-based virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based)):

   ```xml
   <Service name="Catalina">
     <Connector port="80"/>
     <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="host1.localhost">
       <Host name="host1.localhost"  appBase="webapps/host1.localhost"/>
       <Host name="host2.localhost"  appBase="webapps/host2.localhost"/>
     </Engine>
   </Service>
   ```
4. Use two different context paths: just name your WAR files according to the context path, replacing slashes `/` with hashes `#`.

**Remarks**: On a production server:

- Option 1 (IP-based virtual hosting) is usually discarded, because public IP addresses are expensive (though IPv6 addresses are not...),
- Option 2 (Port-based virtual hosting) is usually discarded, because web sites on non-standard ports are not easily scanned by search engine bots and may be considered non-legitimate (every UNIX user can run a server on port 8080, only root on port 80). If you use non-standard ports you'll probably want to use a reverse proxy.
- It might be a good practice to run your applications with a non-empty context path, so that any errors preventing your application from running with a non-empty path (e.g. absolute links that don't include the context path) are caught during testing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have several ip addresses on one machine, that's what ports are for. You assign a port to an application, in `application.properties`, eg. `server.port = 8081`.

Now, paths are assigned by `Controllers` and their methods, eg.

```
@Controller("/first")
publc class FirstController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

**edit**
I think you're talking about the context path, which you can specify also in `application.properties` like so: `server.servlet.context-path = /mycontext`.

Comment: _"You cannot have several ip addresses on one machine"_: yes, you can. In fact all the addresses of the form `127.X.Y.Z` are routed to the machine itself.

Comment: I know about these paths. But there comes another path which is the project name running on the server. This path goes before the path you mentioned in your answer.

Comment: @Partho63 I've added an edit to my answer